# Can I obtain a "developer certificate" and "provisioning profile" without a Mac?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deploy Phonegap app to iPhone without having Apple hardware (iPhone + Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339945/how-to-deploy-phonegap-app-to-iphone-without-having-apple-hardware-iphone-mac)

PhoneGap provides a service called "PhoneGap Build" that handles compiling all of your code for you. However, before it will compile anything for an iPhone, it requires that you upload a "developer certificate" and "provisioning profile". Is there any way to obtain a certificate and provisioning profile without using a Mac?

Here is what the people at PhoneGap have to say: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with PhoneGap Build and found this link for generating a certificate signing request on Windows.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-8000.html

I just went through the process and it appeared to work fine. I've now uploaded it to Apple and am waiting on the "Pending Issuance".

While I was looking around for this solution I found another great article here that looks like it addresses what happens after you get this far.

[Convert push certificate to P12 format on Windows for iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670475/convert-push-certificate-to-p12-format-on-windows-for-iphone-app)