# Creating app for ios in phonegap build

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

We are developing mobile apps for our web application. We started doing it by Phonegap. We created a simple app using html,css and javascript and tried to upload into PhoneGap Build, its able to create apps for android, windows but not able to create for ios. I have googled about it, i got some information that i need to take apple
developers program account and establish the mac environment locally to get the signing certificate from apple.
Here my questons are:
- why we need to establish mac environment, even i use phonegap(which is for hybrid app environment)?
- If yes(should set up the mac environment), how to do it?

Comment: If you want to build a native application, you need a MAC environment and, at least, a Developer Program from Apple.

Comment: I am not developing native app. i am developing hybrid app using phonegap

Comment: Have a look over the links for certificate and provisioning without a MAC. you do not need a Mac for certificate and provisioning. links [here](http://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/iapproach-mobile-development-made-elegant/deploying-to-iphone-without-a-mac-with-an-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442399/can-i-obtain-a-developer-certificate-and-provisioning-profile-without-a-mac) for details

Comment: Thank you frank, I came to know that we don't need mac os instead we can do it by windows itself. I created CertificateSigningRequest, Now where should i get the certificates for ios, Shouls i take ios developer program paid account?

Answer (score 1):

Even you use phonegap, you still have to have a key for iOS development.

You can read the phonegap build docs about this topic : [iOS Signing](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/signing_signing-ios.md.html)

They clearly say that:

> Since PhoneGap Build uses Apple's standard development process to build applications, you will need to sign up for their developer program to build iOS applications on PhoneGap Build. You will also need a Mac to configure your certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: you do not need a Mac for certificate and provisioning. See [here](http://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/iapproach-mobile-development-made-elegant/deploying-to-iphone-without-a-mac-with-an-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442399/can-i-obtain-a-developer-certificate-and-provisioning-profile-without-a-mac) for details